# Add row to a table populated by thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

When I add a new row into a table populated by thymeleaf I found several issues.

1. I cannot assign any stat.index
2. The th:xxx tags are not represented when I add the rows by using javascript

This is my HTML+thymeleaf code:

```
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tableBody" th:each="branch, stat : *{branchesVO}">
            <td>
                <input type="number" th:value="*{id}" th:field="*{branch[__${stat.index}__].id}" hidden="true" />
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label th:text="#{customerInfo}"/>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="customerInfo" th:value="*{customerInfo}" th:placeholder="#{customerInfo}" th:field="*{branches[__${stat.index}__].customerInfo}"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label th:text="#{address}" />
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" th:value="*{address}" th:placeholder="#{address}" th:field="*{branches[__${stat.index}__].address}"
                                th:required="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label th:text="#{telephone}" />
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="telephone" th:value="*{telephone}" th:placeholder="#{telephone}" th:field="*{branches[__${stat.index}__].telephone}"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label th:text="#{mobilePhone}" />
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="mobile" th:value="*{cellPhone}" th:placeholder="#{mobilePhone}" th:field="*{branches[__${stat.index}__].cellPhone}"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label th:text="#{contact}" />
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="contact" th:value="*{contact}" th:placeholder="#{contact}" th:field="*{branches[__${stat.index}__].contact}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div>
    <hr/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" th:text="#{addBranch}" onclick="addBranch(document.getElementById('table'))"/>
</div>
```

This is my js code:

```
function addBranch(table) {

    var tableRow = "<tr>" +
        "<td>" +
        "<input type='number' th:value='*{id}' th:field='*{branch[__${stat.index}__].id}' hidden='true' />" +
        "<div>" +
        "<div>" +
        "<div class='form-group col-md-6'>" +
        "<label th:text='#{customerInfo}'/>" +
        "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='customerInfo' th:value='*{customerInfo}' th:placeholder='#{customerInfo}' th:field='*{branches[__${stat.index}__].customerInfo}'/>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='form-group col-md-6'>" +
        "<label th:text='#{address}'/>" +
        "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='address' th:value='*{address}' th:placeholder='#{address}' th:field='*{branches[__${stat.index}__].address}' th:required='required'/></div></div>" +
        "<div><div class='form-group col-md-4'>" +
        "<label th:text='#{telephone}'/>" +
        "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='telephone' th:value='*{telephone}' th:placeholder='#{telephone}' th:field='*{branches[__${stat.index}__].telephone}'/>" +
        "</div><div class='form-group col-md-4'>" +
        "<label th:text='#{mobilePhone}'/>" +
        "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='mobile' th:value='*{cellPhone}' th:placeholder='#{mobilePhone}' th:field='*{branches[__${stat.index}__].cellPhone}'/>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='form-group col-md-4'>" +
        "<label th:text='#{contact}'/>" +
        "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='contact' th:value='*{contact}' th:placeholder='#{contact}' th:field='*{branches[__${stat.index}__].contact}'/>" +
        "</div></div></div></td></tr>";

    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    row.innerHTML = tableRow;
}
```

is there any way to make this js (or any other better solution for thymeleaf) add new rows correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Thymeleaf is a **server** side templating engine.
This means that the th:value attribute resolution happens at the server.

The javascript code on the other side runs on the **cient** side.

If you want to add rows to a table on the client side, you'll have to use a little bit of trickery:

```
<script th:inline="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    // OK
    var username = /*[[${user.name}]]*/ 'Test User';
    console.log(username);
    // MAY CAUSE TROUBLE
    var branch_id = 1;
    var url = /*[[@{/branches/}]]*/ '' + branch_id;
    console.log(url);
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Notice a few things:

1. Added `th:inline="javascript"` special attribute tells the Thymeleaf engine to inline the content of the tag.
2. The content has been wrapped with `/*<![CDATA[*/` and `/*]]>*/` (I think this part is necessary for the XML parser)
3. Thymeleaf syntax (`${}`, `*{}`, `@{}`, `#{}`) should be wrapped with `/*[[` and `]]*/`.
4. You can (and should) provide a default static value to the Js variable.
5. You should not mix JavaScript operations (like string concatenation) with the in-lining, or you may get some weird behavior.

---

#### Read more on:

[What is the Syntax to get Thymeleaf ${pageContext.request.contextPath}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242554/what-is-the-syntax-to-get-thymeleaf-pagecontext-request-contextpath)

[Tutorial: Using Thymeleaf - 12.2 Script inlining (JavaScript and Dart)](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart)

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it tonight and I'll give you my feedback!

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem. Could you please be more specific in explaining how to apply javascript inline to add rows to a table?