# How to get content path in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a project using springboot 1.5.10, eclipse IDE and Thymeleaf.

In several pages I have redirections like this in jquery:

eg: In a Select Option

```
$('#month').on('change', function() {

    window.location = "/dashboard/operation/month/" + month;
})
```

eg: In a Button

```
$('#bFind').click(function() {
  var newUrl = "/dashboard/operation/month/";
  newUrl += month;
  $('a').attr('href', newUrl);
});
```

Both redirect works great defined in my Controller.

The urls are:
 http://localhost:8080/dashboard/operation/month/01

But the problem is when I create a war project to deploy it in my apache tomcat 9.0.6 I have to give a name to deploy.

Once you have deployed the url is:
 http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/dashboard/operation/month/01

and it breaks the stuff...

**mywebapp** could be another name.

So I have been looking for add context path:

The main info I found is:

[What is the Syntax to get Thymeleaf ${pageContext.request.contextPath}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242554/what-is-the-syntax-to-get-thymeleaf-pagecontext-request-contextpath?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But when I add this to may header.html file I get always undefined

```
<meta name="ctx" th:content="${#httpServletRequest.getContextPath()}" />
```

Maybe is there is another way to do this and add the context path correctly.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I think it is the problem with your clientside, not serverside, setting location with '/' at the beginning always return the server root (localhost:8080/)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

Maybe try this:

`<meta name="ctx" th:content="@{/}" />`

If the context is localhost:8080, it will output

`<meta name="ctx" content="/" />`

But if your context is localhost:8080/mywebapp it will output

`<meta name="ctx" content="/mywebapp/" />`