# How to get context path in controller without set in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to know if it possible to get the context path in my controller without set the value in application.properties

```
server.contextPath
```

When I create a war to deploy in an apache tomcat server I get something like this:

```
mywebapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

so just simple I change name to **"mywebapp"** and deploy.

But if I want to change to **"mywebapp2"** and have two webapps running I need to change the value in server.contextPath.

I would like to do something like I do in thymeleaf:

[How to get content path in thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630770/how-to-get-content-path-in-thymeleaf/49631480#49631480)

where I get the context-path without worring about the name, but instead of thymeleaf in my java controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a formal parameter `HttpServletRequest request` in the handler method of your controller. Then call [request.getContextPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()).